# Toggle Bluetooth using wired keyboard on iMac

Tags: keyboard, imac, bluetooth, mouse

Every so often my iMac looses the Bluetooth mouse connection. The only way to resolve this (other than a reboot) is to switch Bluetooth off, wait about 10 seconds then switch it back on.

This involves plugging-in a wired mouse, make the above happen, then unplug it.

I use a wired keyboard which continues working without Bluetooth. Is there a way I can set something up, or a keyboard shortcut, to switch off Bluetooth, wait, then switch it back on?

Comment: Thanks Nimash,  This works, although it's Alt and Space for Siri on my Mac.  This is simple, it works and as its a desktop iMac I alway shave internet.

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked :) I didn't get notified of your comment (as you commented on your question and not my answer :)). I noticed it just by chance. You could have commented on my answer, or mentioned me by prepending an `@` before my user name. If you find the answer helpful, consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark shown beside the answer and upvoting it :)

Answer (score 4):

Nimesh’s answer is very clever and requires no extra tools, so that may be what you want.

However, there is a much easier way, if you are willing to spend a few minutes to download and install some apps/tools *once* in order to have a simpler way to turn Bluetooth off/on in the future.

First, download and install `blueutil` from http://www.frederikseiffert.de/blueutil/download/blueutil.zip

Unzip it, double-click the `Install.command` and enter your password, and it will be installed to `/usr/local/bin/blueutil`.

(If you use [brew](http://brew.sh), ignore the above and just do: `brew install blueutil`)

After that, you just need a way to run it via the keyboard. For that, I highly recommend [Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com), although you could use [LaunchBar](https://obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html) instead.

Assuming you use Alfred, [get this Bluetooth toggle workflow](https://github.com/sonnyhuynh/alfred2-toggle-bluetooth) and you can enable/disable Bluetooth with a few keystrokes.

Answer (score 3):

If you use Siri, you can simply ask it to turn Bluetooth on and off. Just press and hold <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> keys to invoke Siri. Now speak **Turn Off Bluetooth** or **Turn Bluetooth Off**. Wait for desired time, invoke Siri again and speak **Turn On Bluetooth** or **Turn Bluetooth On** to enable it again.

---

There's a second, but a bit clumsy approach you can take, if you don't use Siri, or do not have an active Internet connection. (Using Siri requires an active Internet connection).

Enable **Full keyboard Access** to use <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to move focus to on screen controls. Go to System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts and select **All Controls** for **Full keyboard Access**:

[image]

Now, you can easily toggle Bluetooth using keyboard by following these steps:

1. Press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to open Spotlight.
2. Enter `System Preferences`. Select **System Preferences.app** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to launch it.

[image]

3. Press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> (if required) to move focus to **Search** field. Enter **Bluetooth** and select the entry to open Bluetooth preference pane.

[image]

4. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to move focus to **Turn Bluetooth Off** button. Press <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to turn Bluetooth off. Wait for some time, then press it again to turn Bluetooth back on.

[image]

Using this approach, you can toggle Bluetooth without touching mouse.

Comment: This is really useful too.  Thought I may need to delve into scrips or automator.  I think Siri is my first option as it's simple but I do like to be able to navigate by the keyboard too.  Thanks again.  Alan

Comment: Thank you! Dunno why this wouldn't be the default option; it's not very helpful to only be able to tab to one or two controls.

Answer (score 0):

There is a more direct way to do it is by using inbuilt tools.

[Ctrl + F8 will "move to the status menu in the menu bar".](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204434) Then use the Right arrow to reach the Bluetooth icon, then Down arrow to show options, then Up/Down arrows to navigate the options, and Space to choose.